# OpenVPN - ping duplicates packets

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, ping

There is an issue that I cannot find answer for. I have typical setup OpenVPN - 1 server with 10.8.0.0/24 subnet and a 1 client with 10.8.0.5 address. Whether the connection from the server to the client is established or not and I am trying to ping anything that is not in VPN subnet I receive duplicates, e.g.:

```
root@openvpn:~# ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.209.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from waw02s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.46): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=9.06 ms
64 bytes from waw02s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.46): icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=9.08 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from waw02s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.46): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=14.0 ms
64 bytes from waw02s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.46): icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=14.0 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from waw02s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.46): icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=8.67 ms
64 bytes from waw02s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.46): icmp_seq=3 ttl=49 time=8.69 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from waw02s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.46): icmp_seq=4 ttl=50 time=17.9 ms
64 bytes from waw02s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.46): icmp_seq=4 ttl=49 time=18.0 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from waw02s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.46): icmp_seq=5 ttl=50 time=23.8 ms
64 bytes from waw02s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.46): icmp_seq=5 ttl=49 time=23.8 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from waw02s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.46): icmp_seq=6 ttl=50 time=9.56 ms
64 bytes from waw02s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.46): icmp_seq=6 ttl=49 time=9.59 ms (DUP!)
```

My question here is - is it normal or there is some configuration to be corrected on client or server side?